# When memory booster kills my app, it force closes

Tags: java, android

I've programmed an app which have Main activity, Service and Broadcast receiver. The app, works until i'm trying to kill it with app called memory booster. Then it force closes and my logcat throws 2 NULLPOINTEREXCEPTIONS. On my textview (declared in mainactivity and passed to broadcast receiver ), and ConnectiviyManager ( declared in main activity also, but using in Broadcast receiver ).

```
01-24 16:25:06.790: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=ACTION_PERFORMED (has extras) } in app.wifito3g.Broadcast@40628910
01-24 16:25:06.790: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

01-24 16:25:06.790: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at app.wifito3g.Broadcast.onReceive(Broadcast.java:122)

Can anyone explains me why ?
Thanks!

EDIT: Detailed stacktrace

[image]

and line 122 is:

```
wifi_state = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
```

If i comment out line 121, i get NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION ON NEXT LINE which is:

```
wifi_check.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Whenever you kill an application it may behave unexpectedly.

Comment: The problem is, when memory is low, android kills my app, and then it force closes again.

Comment: See my answer. It is normal that you are geting a force close and null pointer exception. You are killing your app and your services related to this app continue working. You have to think about closing properly everything.

Comment: you need to provide some code ... where `conMan` is initialized? is this static(defined in AndroidManifest.xml) or dynamic(from code) BroadcastReciver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out what was wrong. Here is the solution.

1. When task manager or whatever app, kills my app it force closes. Thats because from 2.2 Android version you cannot FULLY kill app with other app for that purpose. Android just wont allow that.
2. When task manager or whatever app "kills" my app, and this app has a running services, an android OS, wants them to run again, so it starts running services again.
3. Because activity is DEAD and there i instantiated my objects they cannot be used in service  again. Some objects MUST be instantiated in service class which i made. ( so they are not null )
4. So i made an instance of WifiManager and other important objects in my custom service class. When OS starts Service again , they are instantiated and ready on use (They are not null )

Sorry for my bad english .. hope you understand what i tried to say :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do: override the onDestroy of your main activity, and there, close everything properly (your services, broadcast etc). In this case, you wil not get a force close anymore.

Comment: first ... this is not a solution to this problem, second ... onDestroy will or will not be called ...

Comment: @Selvin, The user asked why he is geting a a force close, I gave him a logical answer, everybody can agree with that. 2nd, if you check the documentation: onDestroy() = The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Comment: @Milos: `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, and in this case may not be called, depending on the version of Android and the implementation of the API calls behind this "memory booster" app.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I read about this, but which method to call then if the onDestroy is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Milos none... The application is forcefully closed with this 'memory booster' tool. It is totally expected that this result in exiting problems as this is not normal for the application life-cycle...

Comment: @Veger, yes, that's true, but the user is using this tool in order to simulate the system close of his application. So, when the system will close his app in order to manage memory usage, the onDestroy should be called, right?

Comment: @Milos if the application is *properly* closed, the `onDestroy()` method is called (as being a part of properly closing the application). But, I do not know whether this tool closes application properly... (I suspect not, as you don't need a special tool to properly close applications!)

Comment: @Veger, the user's main problem is that his app is force closed when the memory of his phone is low. We can deduce that from his comment: **"The problem is, when memory is low, android kills my app, and then it force closes again"**. So i think that he took this tool to simulate the closing of his app, which is not a good idea because this tool will probably **not react as the android system**. So, by closing **properly** all his services in **onDestroy** will solve his problem when his app will be closed by Android system due to the low memory.

Comment: I am not convinced... His log shows a NPE, this has probably nothing to do with closing services, it has more likely something to do with using uninitialized objects (might be due to early closing the application and being cleanup before actually be initialized). Which is what @CommonsWare is suggesting as well (with not too many words unfortunately)

Comment: @Veger, I think that the broadcast receiver is causing the problem. The receiver is running separetly from the app and needs some app objects as conMan. When his app is destroyed, the conMan object is null and the broadcast receiver tryes to access this null object, so there is the NPE. If he tryes to close all the services and unregister his receivers with `Context.unregisterReceiver()`, it should be fine then. I haven't tested it but it seems logical.

Answer (score 0):

`conMan` is `null` because, in whatever code path you ran down, you have not initialized it. Determine a better place to initialize that value that covers this case.